# Android key lost

Tags: android

I have a very unique situation. I need to introduce and upgrade on the Android market, but I have lost the key store I used at the time as I have changed machines.
Now the Android market won't let me upload the update.
What do I do to find the earlier key?

Answer (score 6):

> what do i do to find the earlier key ?

Get your other machine back. Or, restore the key from a backup you made of the other machine.

Comment: i have the apk file, not the key file. what do i do ? i cant get the earlier comp back it kind of got destroyed.

Comment: @user434885: You cannot recover your keystore from an APK file. If you did not back up your keystore, you will never be able to update this application. You will need to ship a new application, with a new package, and perhaps remove the old one from the Market.

Answer (score 0):

Without the old key you could not update your version, so please find your key.